# How to assign name attribute to dynamic select options with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

From the following example in [this link](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/coll_select_options.asp) I want to set car model as a name attribute by selecting or changing car model options.
currently its giving car name as value for the second select option (carmodel)

```js
var carsAndModels = {};
carsAndModels['VO'] = ['V70', 'XC60', 'XC90'];
carsAndModels['VW'] = ['Golf', 'Polo', 'Scirocco', 'Touareg'];
carsAndModels['BMW'] = ['M6', 'X5', 'Z3'];

function ChangeCarList() {
  var carList = document.getElementById("car");
  var modelList = document.getElementById("carmodel");
  var selCar = carList.options[carList.selectedIndex].value;
  while (modelList.options.length) {
    modelList.remove(0);
  }
  var cars = carsAndModels[selCar];
  if (cars) {
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < cars.length; i++) {
      var car = new Option(cars[i], i);
      modelList.options.add(car);
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<select id="car" onchange="ChangeCarList()">
  <option value="">-- Car --</option>
  <option value="VO">Volvo</option>
  <option value="VW">Volkswagen</option>
  <option value="BMW">BMW</option>
</select>

<select id="carmodel"></select>
```

its inserting car model's index number with name instead of car model name.with `var_dump($_POST['model']);` its giving `string(1) "1"`

Comment: `name` isn't a valid attribute of an `option` so you cannot add it. You could use `data-name` instead though: `car.dataset.name = cars[i];`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan can you give it as answer with code tool.

Comment: The only code you need is the line in the previous comment. I added the answer for you, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`name` isn't a valid attribute of an `option` so you cannot add it. You could use `data-name` instead though:

```
car.dataset.name = cars[i];
```

```js
var carsAndModels = {};
carsAndModels['VO'] = ['V70', 'XC60', 'XC90'];
carsAndModels['VW'] = ['Golf', 'Polo', 'Scirocco', 'Touareg'];
carsAndModels['BMW'] = ['M6', 'X5', 'Z3'];

function ChangeCarList() {
  var carList = document.getElementById("car");
  var modelList = document.getElementById("carmodel");
  var selCar = carList.options[carList.selectedIndex].value;
  while (modelList.options.length) {
    modelList.remove(0);
  }
  var cars = carsAndModels[selCar];
  if (cars) {
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < cars.length; i++) {
      var car = new Option(cars[i], i);
     car.dataset.name = cars[i]; // <- add the data-name here
      modelList.options.add(car);
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<select id="car" onchange="ChangeCarList()">
  <option value="">-- Car --</option>
  <option value="VO">Volvo</option>
  <option value="VW">Volkswagen</option>
  <option value="BMW">BMW</option>
</select>

<select id="carmodel"></select>
```

Comment: its inserting an invalid number with name instead of car model

Comment: Can you edit your question to show that happening, as from your original code it works fine, as you can see in the demo above

Comment: its inserting model's index number with name instead of car model name. I checked it with `var_dump($_POST['model']);` its giving `string(1) "1"`

Comment: That's because you're sending `i` as the value, which is the integer in the loop. If you want the car model name to be sent use just `new Option(cars[i])` instead